# How to show custom validation message in checkout?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, validation

I have created some coupons. when a coupon applied it dispatch an event **salesrule_validator_process**.

In the observer I will check some condition. based on condition the coupon will apply to the cart. But here how can I show a custom validation message if coupon not allowed?

> Observer

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{   
    //return $this;
    $rule           =   $observer->getEvent()->getRule()->getData();
    $couponCode    =   $rule['coupon_code'];
    $customerId     =   $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getData('entity_id');

    $userId     =   '';
    $validity   =   -1; 

    $userId    =   $this->_rule->customerIdToUserId($customerId);
    $validity  =   $this->_rule->checkPromoRule($userId,$couponCode);

    if ($validity == 0) {
        $this->_logger->debug("Coupon Not Valid");
        $this->_logger->critical("Couponcode Not Allowed");
        $this->_qoute->getQuote()->setCouponCode(NULL)->save();
        return $this;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface` class to show success or failure messages in observer.

Comment: $this->_messageManager->addError(__("Error"));  this is not showing any messages. I used namespace , extended constructor and compiled. but its not showing any mesagges.